# p-value in interpreting path coefficients in path modeling of PLS-SEM

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons

I'm beginner at statistics, so my question may seem to have non sense for some.

I was trying to interpret a PLS-SEM results, which is a kind of path modeling. The results of path coefficients are reoported by the corresponding Beta value along with bootstrapping minimum and maximum percentiles.

I recognized variations in the p value used for t-test for each path coefficient, some are 0.1%, others are 1%, others are 5%, others are 10%, (the single and multiple stars and # at the attached photo), so what is the notion behind using multiple values for p? is that ok? I have (mostly wrong) idea that the same p value has to be used in all the tests for different paths' coefficients.

Attached  photo of the results.

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with PLS-SEM and everything to do with how p-values are interpreted. You have hit the nail on the head about the ambiguous interpretaton.

Comment: Jermey, I am not sure I got your point. Do you mean that it is not OK to have multiple p values for different path coefficients?

Comment: That's a surprisingly complicated question. Whether it's OK or not has nothing to do with PLS-SEM. Here's an article that explains the issues: https://www.mpib-berlin.mpg.de/volltexte/institut/dok/full/gg/ggstehfda/ggstehfda.html